# AssetLoader doesn't reload textures after they have been disposed LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have set up an AssetLoader class in my Android project and I use     `AssetLoader.dispose()` to dispose my textures after I switch game screens and `AssetLoader.load()` when I start my app so all my assets are loaded when the game is opened. The problem is, when I come back to a screen I previously closed, all the textures are gone! What can I do to dispose the textures to prevent memory leaks without making them disappear forever?

Comment: reload screen specific texture asynchronously and display a reactive loading screen while things load

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?(sorry, I am relatively new to LibGDX)

Comment: create Texture or load Texture into AssetsManager before you want to use but after disposing you can't use that asset so you need to recreate that Texture

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Comment: Once dispose is called on AssetManager, it is no longer usable. If you want to unload stuff but keep using your AssetManager, use unload().

Comment: If your game doesn't use a large amount of memory for textures, don't bother unloading at all. Simply dispose when the entire game is shutting down in the Game's `dispose()` method.